# Store Image from URL to localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a JSON string as below which contains the path of an image.  The image exists in the server

```
"send-sms":{
   "menu_name":"Send",
   "menu_icon":"http:\/\/example.com\/mob\/media\/com_abcd\/icons\/send.png"
}
```

This is my meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data: http://example.com">
```

I want to store the image to a local session.  I use the below Javascipt where I pass the full image URL.  It always returns null.

```
function getImageData(imgpath){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imgpath;
    var data = null;

    img.load = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        data = context.getImageData(x, y, img.width, img.height).data;
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem('mysession_imag', data);
    };

}
```

Comment: This is an async problem. Put the `setItem` call inside your `img.load` callback. You may run into this other problem later, though:  [Cross Domain Images and the Tainted Canvas](http://blog.codepen.io/2013/10/08/cross-domain-images-tainted-canvas/)

Comment: @apsillers I moved the `setItem` inside the load.  I also updated the question with the meta I have.  I got `undefined` for the image...

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you have an `async` call.

The code will run in the steps I have mentioned in the comments.

In short, you are creating a second variable, also called `data` and then doing nothing with it.

```
function getImageData(imgpath){
    var img = new Image();
   img.src = imgpath;

    // Step 1: Yes, data is `null`.  You are setting it that way.
    data = null;

    img.load = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Step 3:  You are creating a NEW data variable
        var data = context.getImageData(x, y, img.width, img.height).data;

        // Step 4: And doing nothing with it.
    };

    // Step 2: You are storing the `null` from step 1
    localStorage.setItem('mysession_imag', data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the `data`.  I updated my question and still data comes null.

Comment: Note the ORDER the steps run it. You are SETTING data via `localStorage` before step 3 runs.

Comment: ahhh.. ok. I moved the `localStorage` inside the load function.  Not sure whether I can do `console.log` but when I do `console.log` it returns `undefined`...

Comment: At this point, you've now get a different issue.  I've never used cross-domain canvas, but @apsillers gave a hint in his comment above.

Comment: what is x and y?

Comment: @Xvegas I just used the code given in the OP's question, but `x` and `y` would be declared in the outer scope.